# Как ускорить печать документов в минт 19

Tags: linux-mint, принтер

Как ускорить печать документов в минт 19?
Нужно напечатать одностраничный документ (.xls или pdf) три раза на принтере HP LaserJet P1102W. Принтер подключен к локальной беспроводной сети.  В окне "Состояние печати документа" появляются три задания на печать. В течении  10-30 минут происходит печать первого задания. Два следующих задания не выполняются.
Удаляю эти звдания. Повторяю печать снова, но все повторяется!
Что происходит?

Comment: @Андрей, мой комментарий относился к первой редакции вопроса, в которой ничего практически не было.

Comment: с виндовс отправляются нормально? Обычно проблема или в драйверах (описании работы, способе подключения) или настройках cups

Answer (score 0):

Валерий, проблема скорее всего не с ОС, у меня  *HP M130nw*, печать по воздуху с macOS, Windows или даже с телефона происходит с дикой задержкой, задержки появляются после простоя в режиме ожидания.

Как лечить не знаю, но для срочных печатей приходится либо перезапустить принтер либо печатать через USB интерфейс *(через USB все молниеносно)*

Comment: Aндрей, спасибо за ответ! Все-таки кто-то читает сообщения форума. Вы используете одновременно оба варианта подключения - wifi и usb?

Comment: @Valery USB использую только в экстренных случаях когда нету времени ждать когда-же раздуплится принтер при срочных печатях